# How do I connect a page on my website to post on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I was searching for a while, but probably I'm just not using the right keywords.

Right now I have two separate things:

1) Articles on my website. Each article has a facebook like/recommend this article button at the end of the article. I.e. you can scroll to the bottom of the article here - http://www.thecheers.org/Travel/article_4915_Ryanair---how-can-they-fly-with-their-prices.html - you'll probably see that there's a text next to the button saying that "13 people recommend this".

2) I have a facebook page which has also posted a link to this article there. The post on Facebook page has a couple of likes.

The question - how can I make it so that when someone clicks the Recommend button on my website, it would also update the number of post likes on my facebook page? Keeping in mind that I am not talking about Facebook page likes but individual facebook post/article likes.

Any ideas? IN theory, it sounds like it should be easy...yet right now it doesn't really look like it.

Comment: Your external article, and your post on Facebook that happens to link to that article, are two different entities. You can not “combine” the individual likes you get on either of them.

Answer (score 0):

Number of likes on a Facebook publication can be only increased by "real people" liking via Facebook. No third-party integration or API can deal with likes counter.